# How to insert the star rating into firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code and I can only get it to work logically if I set the star rating to hidden first and then let the user rate the star after they have given the review. I am not sure how it works but the rating of the star only gets inserted into the database if the user click on the star. I tried to put this under the setOnClickListener for my button, so that the rating score should be sent together with the review but it doesn't work. I have to do this outside my button....

```
add_review_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference();
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String clinic_info = String.valueOf(childSnapshot.child("Name").getValue());
                    final String txt_review = review.getText().toString().trim();
                    String txt_dorevitch = dorevitch.getText().toString().trim();
                    String txt_skin_cancer = skin_cancer_check.getText().toString().trim();
                    String txt_ear_suctioning = ear_suctioning.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_email = user.getText().toString().trim();
                    String user_email2 = Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getEmail();
                    String other = others.getText().toString().trim();
                    String input = input_others.getText().toString().trim();

                    //   replace(":" ,"");
                    //    message[0] = message[0].replaceAll("[0-9]" ,"");
                    //   message[0] = message[0].replace("Shop" ,"");
                    //   if (clinic_info.equals(message[0]) && !user_email.isEmpty() && user_email.equals(user_email2) && !txt_review.isEmpty()) {
                        user_email = user_email.split("\\s*@\\s*")[0];
                        final HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("Review by " + user_email, txt_review);
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child(message[0]).child("Reviews").updateChildren(map);
                        // rating bar code

                        ratingbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        final String finalUser_email = user_email;
                        ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                                int rate = (int) rating;
                                String info = null;

                                myRating = (int) ratingBar.getRating();

                                switch (rate) {
                                    case 1:
                                        info = "Sorry to hear that! :( ";
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        info = "We always accept suggestions!";
                                        break;
                                    case 3:
                                        info = "Good enough!";
                                        break;
                                    case 4:
                                        info = "Great! Thanks you!";
                                        break;
                                    case 5:
                                        info = "Awesome! You are the best!";
                                        break;
                                }

                                Toast.makeText(Add_Review.this, info, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                HashMap<String, Object> map5 = new HashMap<>();
                                map5.put("Rating by " + finalUser_email, rate);



                                Toast.makeText(Add_Review.this, "Review Successfully Submited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child(message[0]).child("Rating").updateChildren(map5);

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: I also just noticed that it is inside my button section but still, the rating does not get sent through together...

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your rating is saved only when user clicks the star is because the  updateChildren code is inside the onRatingChangeListener.

Is is not working if you keep updateChildren command outside the the onRatingChangeListener and inside the review button onClickListener?

Also try this :

1. Keep the onRatingChangeListener outside the review Button;s OnclickListener.
2. Declare the `info` variable as public so that it can be used in both functions i.e OnRatingChangeListener ( which will save rating in the `info` variable ) and then the button's OnclickListener ( which will save the rating to database using `info` variable)

Comment: I tried moving it outside the OnclickListener but it doesn't seem to like it... the brackets won't closed but shouldn' we be using updateChildren anyway?

Comment: I also tried using setValue but that does the same thing

Comment: it is a small problem... I can always do it this way setting it to hidden

Comment: is it necessary to set the raing to hidden, it should work without it as well. This is how i use it,

Comment: you mentioned the bracket wont close, can you describe what you meant by this?

Comment: No matter where I put the bracket, it will keep showing an error or highlight in red...

Comment: See this piece of code has no brackets issue:

https://gist.github.com/maheensaleh/0b589df5f72ae907d392b839cff73569

Comment: also , i noticed that the firebase update command in inside the addValueEventListsener which means that the update command runs only when a value is added to this database reference

Comment: I guess I need to do it this way because of my logic that I am using... trying to match certain things from the database